# Write VBA code for AccessDB to convert a lat/long to geod. northing/easting Zone 4501 VA SP north only

Tags: ms-access, vba, latitude-longitude, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

I am having a lot of trouble writing a code that will read in a latitude and longitude (NAD83) from a form, and convert them to VA State Plane North METRIC northing and easting.  I am currently using Corpscon Beta 7 to convert a lat/long pair, but this requires that I go to an external resource to do so. I would like to preform the conversion in the database, so I can then query values from a table based on the northing and easting values.

I know that to transform the coordinates, I must use the following variables (I have already sourced their respective values):

*Semi-major axis = 6378137.000*

*Semi-minor axis = 6356752.314*

*Central Meridian Scale Factor = 0.99994*

*First/Souther Parallel Lat. = 38.0333 deg*

*Second/Northern Parallel Lat. = 39.20 deg*

*Grid Origin Lat. = 37.6667 deg*

*Central Meridian Long. = 78.50 deg*

*False Easting = 3500000 m*

*False Northing = 2000000 m*

I have done hours of researching and creating code, but nothing seems to produce accurate results, and most code that is found is converting Northing/Easting to Lat/Long, OR is done in a completely different language... and unfortunately I lack the knowledge to read and convert the code.

Comment: Geo experts are rare birds here, it's mostly a coder area. So I am afraid you will have to give a bit more explanations on the maths/trigo/formulas to convert from one system to another...

Comment: This question currently is too broad in my opinion. I very much doubt you can do this without a really substantial amount of code in VBA, and requests for off-site resources such as libraries that can do this are off-topic, making it unfit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Could you provide some sample input/output?

Comment: Sample Input: 
Latitude: 38.80664166
Longitude: 77.2137167677342
(I have converted the lat and long to northing and easting values using corpscon, a USGS Excel Workbook/Program resource provided online) 
I am trying to write a VBA code in Access that would read in these values from their textboxes, and would then convert them to northing and easting values, using the constants i stated in my original post. All of latitudes and longitudes are in VA State Plane North Zone 4501, so I can define those within the code and not have to worry about them changing

Comment: If corpscon exposes its VBA code, and the license permits, can't you just copy and modify the corpscon code? Since it's Excel, it is almost certainly VBA.

Comment: Yes, they do expose parts of its code. When you download corpscon, you also download hundreds of files of various types that are then read in the VBA code within the user corpscon workbook. I was unable to obtain any useful lines of code from the VBA